# How to stop Eclipse from splitting annotations into new lines

Tags: java, eclipse

```
@Setter
@Getter
private String query;
```

I get something like this after formatting, how to prevent it and keep my annotations in one line? I didn't find any usable setting inside Formater configuration.

```
@Setter @Getter @sthElse @oneMore @etc
private String query;
```

This is how I would like it to be

Comment: I would love if Eclipse implemented that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One hack that allows you to force a newline whenever you want is to add a in-line comment (`//`) to the end of the line.  For example, when I have annotations on parameters, I want them to line up like this:

```
public ModelView finish(//
        @PathParam("stampId")//
        long stampId, //
```

Instead of like this:

```
public ModelView finish(@PathParam("stampId") long stampId,
```

My use of `//` gives me more fine grained control over this.  So if you change the 
"insert new lines after annotations" setting you should be able to get:

```
@Setter @Getter @sthElse @oneMore @etc //
private String query;
```

I'm sure if I took a look at the Eclipse formatting code I could add it there but I don't have the time for that.  :-)

Comment: Ouch, even in Luna, seems we still have this restriction. I've had to use this _solution_ to satisfy `checkstyle` ... _shudder_! (would be grateful if some one had a nicer solution?)

Answer (score 10):

IMHO the closest you can get is:

```
@Setter @Getter @sthElse @oneMore @etc private String query;
```

(via Formatter->New Lines->Insert new lines after annotations on Method

Comment: I was afraid so... This version is even more ugly :)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the closest solution, but still, it's not a solution. :-(

Answer (score 2):

When you're editing your formatting profile, select the 'New Lines' tab.  There's a grouping labelled 'Annotations' on that preference page.  You should be able to deselect the preferences to "Insert new line after annotations on members/parameters/local variables"

Answer (score 0):

On Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18) or later, [Annotations wrapping settings](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.18/jdt.php#JavaFormatter) exist.

- Line Wrapping > Wrapping settings > Annotations > On fields: **Do not wrap**